# What CLI APPCRASH php.exe while unit testing mean?

Tags: php, windows, netbeans, wamp

**Short:**

- CLI APPCRASH php.exe occur with only one project testing, not occur with another project.
- Yesterday same project with same configuration (php, netbeans, wamp, phpunit) did not cause that error.
- edit: same crash with fresh installed php 7.0.6

**Details:**

Netbeans "Test" option (project context menu) which generate command:

> "..\phpunit.bat" "--colors"
>   "--log-junit" "..\nb-phpunit-log.xml"
>   "..\NetBeans 8.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--"
>   "--run=C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnit-Calculator-PHPUnit1\test\src\CalculatorTest.php"

cause APPCRASH:

[image]

translate:

```
Problem details:
  problem name: APPCRASH
  aplication name:  php.exe
  application version:  7.0.1.0
  Sygnatura czasowa aplikacji:  5671e9a8
  module name with error:   ucrtbase.DLL
  module version with error:    10.0.10240.16390
  exception code:   c0000005
  Moving the exception: 00032a05
  OS version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Identyfikator ustawień regionalnych:  1045
  more information 1:   0a9e
  more information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  more information 3:   0a9e
  more information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

using:
-windows7
-wamp3
-php7.0.1
-netbeans 8.1

Comment: I notice you are on php 7.0.1 - as it's php crashing, are you able to try the latest 7.0.6 release of php ?

Comment: i will do this, (but with same php it crash on one project and not crash on another)

Comment: same crash with fresh installed php 7.0.6